# Pull div behind navbar

Tags: html, css

Vanilla HTML/CSS on SPA:

I have a CSS navbar with the height of 40px. I have a DIV underneath with some content. I did not set the height of the page to 100vh or anything.

I want to have the DIV go "underneath" the navbar, so that the DIV equals exactly 100vh upon loading. In other words, I want the navbar AND DIV combined to be exactly 100vh upon loading so that the first scroll shows the beginning of the 2nd DIV.

```
    <div class="navbar">
        <img src="./img/logo.svg" />
        BUTTONS AND WHATNOT
    </div>

    <div class="home">...</div>
    <div class="2nd div>...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As long as you can go with a fixed height for the navbar I think you can just use css to accomplish this. Try using `calc()` to subtract the navbar height from `100vh` to calculate the height of the first page.

```
height: calc( 100vh - 60px );
```

```css
body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
}

.home {
  height: calc( 100vh - 60px);
  background: green;
}

.second-panel {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <img src="./img/logo.svg" /> BUTTONS AND WHATNOT
</div>

<div class="home">...</div>
<div class="second-panel">...</div>
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but thought it would look petty for me to whine on my own answer, so thanks for asking that! Is this helpful in your situation? If you can't use a fixed navbar height we can do a similar thing with js but you said vanilla html/css.

Comment: @Helle Probably the same "clowns" who will have your question closed in an hour or two for not following SO rules and policy as outlined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JasonB Yes, this will do. Typically, the navbar even on mobile can get away having give or take 50px height. I'll try this, thanks.